# Sum over dates in R studio for formula

Tags: r

I'm working on some Covid-19 related questions in R Studio.

I have a data frame containing the columns of the date, cases (newly infected people on this date), deaths on this date, country, population, and indicator 14, which is the Number of cases per 100,000 residents over the last 14 days including the current date.

Now I want to create a new indicator, which is looking at the cases per 100,000 over the **last 7 days**.

The way to calculate it would of course be: [7 days indicator = (sum from k= i-6 to i of cases_k/population) * 100,000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6zZW.png)

So I wanted to code a function `incidence <- function(cases, population) {}` performing the formula on the data but I'm struggling:

How can I always address the last 7 days?

I know that I can e.g. compute a sum vom 0 to 5 with the following: `i <- 0:5; sum(i^2)` but how do I define from k= i-6 to i in this case?

Do I have to use a loop inside the function?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming the data is sorted by date and there are entries for each date: `x <- 1:10; c(stats::filter(x, rep(1, 7), sides = 1))`

Comment: I like `slider::slide_index_dbl(YOUR_VARIABLE, DATE_COL, sum, .before = lubridate(6))`.